# Ubuntu 17.04 "Black Screen" when trying to login/at startup

Tags: login

When i try to login (at the startup) a black screen with this text shows up:

```
[   2.745742] usb 1-2.1: string descriptor 0 read error: -22

BusyBox V1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-19ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

I'm thinking about re-installing ubuntu via usb but i just wanna know if there's a way to solve this problem without having to re-install the whole OS and deleting all my documents.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug all unnecessary USB devices, then at the (initramfs) prompt, type `fsck -f /` and check your file system.

If that doesn't work, use one of these two procedures...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: How do i choose Root access? After choosing the recovery mode a bunch of commands start showig up in the screen, when it finishes the (initframs) _ shows up again, is there something i have to do before choosing Recovery Mode?

Comment: @Alexander did you try the `fsck` command at the (initramfs) prompt as indicated by my first sentence? If that didn't work, and the first procedure sounds like it's not working either, then use the second procedure. Report back.